# Children stories with a little alien, name?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to find out the name of some stories I read as a kid. I remember a little alien that would visit a child at night. I remember the alien going along in the air. I think he wore a clear bubble helmet. I read them in the 70s. I liked them because it was an adventure at night when everyone else was asleep. If I remember correctly the child found the alien to be a bit of a pest.

Comment: Were the stories in a series?

Answer (score -1):

Could it be Spaceship under the Apple Tree by Louis Slobdodkin? I read this book series as a 6 year old in the early 60's. It was my first introduction to science fiction although it probably would be more accurate to categorize them as fantasy now.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE JBR549! Maybe you'd like to add why you think *Spaceship under the Apple Tree* is a likely answer.

Comment: I read the *Spaceship* books in the 1970s (there were two, that I'm aware of), and they don't match this question at all -- no bubble helmet, no nighttime visits, and the human boy's grandmother (who was raising him) even met the alien (he fixed her ripped screen door with some of his power wire), though I don't believe she ever figured out he wasn't from Earth.

Comment: Im actually reading that one now to see if that is it...cost $20 paperback. Apparently they are collectible.